# Sending file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, file

I'm creating spring boot application that send a file in body response, to this i use this code :

```
FileSystemResource pdfFile = new FileSystemResource(outputFile);

return ResponseEntity
       .ok()
       .contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
       .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
       .body(new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(pdfFile.getInputStream())));
```

I'm wondering if there's any alternative way for send file other than using FileSystemResource ?

Please, If there's any suggestion, do not hesitate.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified version of how I usually do it, but it does pretty much the same thing:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPdf(@PathVariable Long id) throws IOException {
    final String filePath = pdfFilePathFinder.find(id);

    final byte[] pdfBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", null);
    headers.setCacheControl("no-cache");

    return new ResponseEntity<>(pdfBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: I have a question in this instruction : < final byte[] pdfBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));> the " filePath "is the absolute path or relative path ?

Comment: Absolute. I do not know if it works with relative paths as well, but in either case there are ways to create `Path`s from classpath resources as well, that you can then send into `Files#readAllBytes`. But that's another topic already answered elsewhere.